# Detect play/pause interaction on video element and ignore the events triggered through seek feature

Tags: javascript, video, dom-events, html5-video

I'm having an issue with the video element [events](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/video#events):

I only want to fire off an analytics event when the **play** or **pause** button is interacted with. The `play`, `pause`, and `playing` events work as expected up until the **seek** functionality is used.

I'd like to isolate the play/pause events from the ones fired through seek/seeking.

When the video is **playing** and it is **clicked** (moved to a different point), the `play`, `playing`, and `pause` events are triggered because the video will pause to buffer and start playing the video again. This order is not always the same. When **paused** you don't get any of these events.

When debugging the `playing` and `pause` events, I've seen the following order:

- **Order 1:** `Pause`, `Seeking`, `Seeked`, `Playing`
- **Order 2:** `Pause`, `Playing`, `Seeking`, `Seeked`, `Playing`

This link to [w3.org/mediaevents](https://www.w3.org/2010/05/video/mediaevents.html) gives you a good indication of the above.

I've set up my [own version in jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gvn5hxkq/) (see console logs).

I've tried setting a flag that is reset on a timeout and setting/checking the last state for each event e.g. `lastEvent = 'seeking'`. None of these worked 100% because of the inconsistent fire order. If you drag the seek bar it won't fire the `play`, `playing`, or `paused` events which adds another scenario.

Answer (score 2):

I'm still looking for a real good answer too. So far I have this workaround:

```
    function paused() {
        stateSeeked = false;
        stateEnded = false;
        setTimeout(function () {
            if (!stateSeeked && !stateEnded) {
                active = false;
            }
        }, 200);
    }

    function seek(event) {
        stateSeeked = true;
    }

    function ended() {
        stateEnded = true;
        if (trackDuration !== Infinity) {
            player.audio.src = "";
            player.skipNext();
        } else {
            player.audio.load();
            player.audio.play();
        }
    }
```

This code is for my own player, for the whole code see:
https://github.com/oyosoftware/oyoplayer
I'm also planning to write the visual part of the player myself, with my own pause button. This way I will be certain that I will have a 'real' pause.
It isn't a surprise to me that so far, you didn't have any answers. Me myself couldn't find answers too. It is also a known fact that the HTML5 player has problems with stable buffering. With my own player I have tried to circumvent most problems to my best ability.